# Jquery show and hide rows based on 3 dropdown conditions

Tags: jquery, html-select, custom-data-attribute

I have 2 dropdowns and buttons which I want to show and hide rows based. In the table I am using 3 different data attributes - manufacturer, category and sleeve length. When I have the got values for every dropdown when the value is selected. However I am struggling to to show/hide the correct rows based on what the user selects in the dropdown. I need an if statement or another way which show the correct results based on what the user has selected. I should note that the user could select only one dropdown and see the results. Code is below:

```
var manufacturerSelected;
var categorySelected;
var sleeveLengthSelectd;

manufacturerSelected = "";
categorySelected = "";
sleeveLengthSelectd = "";

$("#selectManufacturer").change(function(event) {
    manufacturerSelected = $(this).val();
    getResults();
});

$("#selectType").change(function(event) {
    categorySelected = $(this).val();
    getResults();
});

$(".btnLength").click(function(event) {
    selectedButton = $(this).html();
    if(selectedButton == "Short Sleeve"){
        $("#shortSleeve").addClass('btnLengthActive');
        $("#longSleeve").removeClass('btnLengthActive');
        sleeveLengthSelectd = "short";
    }else{
        $("#longSleeve").addClass('btnLengthActive');
        $("#shortSleeve").removeClass('btnLengthActive');
        sleeveLengthSelectd = "long";
    }
    getResults();
});

function getResults(){
    $("#productTable tbody tr").each(function() {
        var manufacturer = $(this).attr('data-manufacturer');
        var category = $(this).attr('data-category');
        var sleeveLength = $(this).attr('data-sleeve');
       if(manufacturerSelected == manufacturer){
        $(this).show();
       }else{
        $(this).hide();
       }
       if(categorySelected == category){
        $(this).show();
       }else{
        $(this).hide();
       }
       if(sleeveLengthSelectd == sleeveLength ){
        $(this).show();
       }else{
        $(this).hide();
       }
    });
```

Comment: what you need is `&&` logic. `if (condition1 && condition2 && condition3)`

Comment: Thank you, what about if one of the dropdowns hasn't been selected? As it's possible the user might do that. Will that if statement take into account that?

Comment: if dropdown hasnt been selected has value '', then each condition, you need to check `if ( (manufacturerSelected == "" || manufacturerSelected == manufacturer) && (condition2) && (condition3))`

Comment: Do you mean like this if(((manufacturerSelected == "") || (manufacturerSelected == manufacturer)) && ((categorySelected == "") || (categorySelected == category)) && ((sleeveLengthSelectd == "") || (sleeveLengthSelectd == sleeveLength)))